# get last row or first row of a note in a cell and add to it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Sounds super simple but I can't figure it out. I have a script that updates a note that is built into a cell. The problem is I want it to build upon the note. So either get last row of the note or get first row, doesn't matter to me how It is formatted. The problem is it writes over the previous note.

```
function Note() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var timezone = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-4", "M/dd/yy', 'h:mm a"); // Get the current time;
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().setNote('Notes:\n\n-updated file on ' + timezone + '\n\n' + '-');
};
```

Ideally I would like it to put this note at the top of the note and not write over any other part of the note. This way it is just a running note or log if you will. I am going to add this to many other functions I have running so I have a log of every time a function was run on that file.

Comment: Just to confirm - you want your message appended to the top of the note instead of replacing what's currently set right?

Comment: Yes that would be  perfect

Comment: I am confused what you are adding? Just the                                                                + ' \n' + spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNote());

Comment: I am still a rookie so I don't think I am adding it correctly. I tried it in the setNote(), after the setNote()'s, as well as in a new line. I just don't think I understand the instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function appendNote(note) {
  if(!note) {
    var response=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Append a note:")
    var note=response.getResponseText();
  }
  if(note) {
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
    var ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
    sh.getActiveRange().setNote(ts + note + '\n\n' + sh.getActiveRange().getNote());
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is it doesn't append again. So if I run the script twice it won't add it again. It writes over the old notes. Every time I run the function I need it to append a note to the last note. Its like a time stamp function so I ran the function yesterday it made a note, and then run it again today and it made a new note but the old note is still there.

Comment: You can append it at the end or the beginning depending upon how you arrangement the items in the last command.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H0qwHi_TOCY9k3WpTNazt-im7swMOO2h7AIeyYgNYH8/edit?usp=sharing

Here is a link to the sheet, Can you help out on this, I gave Edit Access. On the 'Follow up email' tab When you push the button it emails anyone on the pivot table, updates my counter in column K, date in I, but I want it to add the note to the note in E that is for that cell.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Just check if the note exists, and if it does, rewrites the note but before it adds the new text.

```
function Note() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ss = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  var timezone = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-4", "M/dd/yy', 'h:mm a"); // Get the current time;
  var range = ss.getActiveRange();
  var note = range.getNote();

  if (note) {
    note = note + '\n\n-updated file on ' + timezone + '\n\n';
    range.setNote(note);

  }else {
    range.setNote('Notes:\n\n-updated file on ' + timezone + '\n\n'); 
    }

}
```